# Prove a differentiable function is continuous

Tags: real-analysis, solution-verification

Prove that $f$ differentiable at $p$ is continuous at $p$.

*Note that proofs of this are readily available on the internet.  My goal here is help with* my *proof.*

**Proof:** Since $f$ is differentiable, there exists a function $\delta_d: (0, \infty) \to (0, \infty)$ such that for all $\epsilon_d > 0$,
$$|h| < \delta_d(\epsilon_d) \implies |f(p+h) - f(p)| < |hf'(p)| + \epsilon_d$$

If $f'(p) = 0$, we are done.  Otherwise, define $\delta_c: (0, \infty) \to (0, \infty)$ as
$$\epsilon_c \mapsto \min(\frac{\epsilon_c}{2|f'(p)|}, \delta_d(\frac{\epsilon_c}{2}))$$

Then, for any $\epsilon_c > 0$,
$$|h| < \delta_c(\epsilon_c) \implies |f(p+h) - f(p)| < |hf'(p)| + \epsilon_c/2 \leq \epsilon_c$$

**Discussion:** I believe my proof is correct, but excessively complicated for what seems like a simple conclusion.  Is my proof needlessly complicated? If so, what is the cause - what step could I do differently to keep it simpler (either in my work leading to a proof, or my exposition of the proof).

My intuition is that the complication comes from my usage of $\epsilon, \delta$ definitions.  [Here](https://math.jhu.edu/%7Ebrown/courses/f17/Documents/DiffImpliesCont.pdf) is a proof which is much simpler, but I can't reverse engineer the proof to figure out how it was inspired.  [Here](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Differentiable_Function_is_Continuous) is an even simpler one.

How would you reach the key ideas needed to form a simpler proof, such as the ones cited? What "crux move" would lead me to realize a [simple proof](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Differentiable_Function_is_Continuous)?

Answer (score 1):

Proofs of this tend to be reflections of the fact that, in order for: $$\lim_{h\to0}\frac{f(x+h)-f(x)}{h}$$To even exist, the numerator must also tend to zero. Else you’d observe $\cdot/0$ blowup along some subsequence.

Your proof can accordingly be simplified. Note that you can actually have:
$$0\le|f(p+h)-f(p)|<|h|\cdot(|f’(p)|+\epsilon_d)$$So you don’t need to mess with these $\delta_\bullet$ functions. *Differentiable functions are locally Lipschitz.* Just specify $\varepsilon_d=1$. I know there is a $\delta>0$ such that $|h|<\delta$ implies: $$0\le|f(p+h)-f(p)|<h(|f’(p)|+1)$$But you can just take $h\to0$ on this inequality, from within $(-\delta,\delta)$, to conclude $|f(p+h)-f(p)|\to0$. If you like, $\forall\epsilon>0$ there is $0<\delta’<\delta$, $\delta’:=\frac{1}{1+|f’(p)|}\epsilon$, such that $|h|<\delta’$ implies: $$0\le|f(x+h)-f(x)|<\epsilon$$

Answer (score 0):

The definition of the differentiability at $p$ says that
$$f(p + h) = f(p) + f'(p)h + o(h).$$
In comparison, the definition of continuity at $p$ says that
$$f(p + h) = f(p) + o(1).$$
It is clear that $f'(p)h + o(h) = o(1)$, so differentiability implies continuity. The "it is clear" relies on the facts that $f'(p)h = o(1)$ and $o(h) = o(1)$. Both of these are very trivial to prove using $\varepsilon$-$\delta$.

Comment: Can you clarify your second equation? $o(1)$ is independent of $h$, whereas $f(p+h)$ is potentially far from $f(p)$ for large $h$.

Comment: @SRobertJames In this context, the $o$ notations are for $h\to0$

Comment: @SRobertJames $r(h) = o(g(h))$ means that $\lim_{h \to 0}r(h)/g(h) = 0$. This is called little-$o$ notation.

Answer (score 0):

Here's how I found a simpler proof.  *Please comment not only on the correctness, but on the **"how to solve it"** of finding a simpler solution.*

The first step is to notice that the OP approach is more complicated than expected, and look for alternate approaches, such as moving from *definitions* (as in the OP) to *computation*.  This means asking:

1. What do I want to compute?
2. Are there any known quantities that might be useful in computing it?

#1 is clear: $\lim_{x \to p} f(x)$.  We wish to show it equals $f(p)$.
#2 is likewise clear: We're given only $\lim_{h \to 0} \frac{f(p+h) - f(p)}{h} = f'(p)$.

We can't immediately use #2 to compute #1, because they are in different "coordinates".  Can we rewrite these quantities so that they use more similar "coordinates"?

We can! We rewrite #1 as $\lim_{h \to 0} f(p+h)$ , putting it in the same "coordinates" as #2.  This then suggests we use #2 to show $\lim_{h \to 0} f(p+h) - f(p) = 0$.

Multiplying both sides of #2 by $h$, we get $lim_{h \to 0}f(p+h)-f(p) = hf'(p) = 0$, QED.